# How to get days between Current & Selected date by using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container,Form,Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Calculation = () => {

    const [stockingDate, setStockingDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [age, setAge] = useState(0);

    const changeHandler = (e)=>{
        setStockingDate(e.target.value);
    }

    const changeCurrentHandler = (e)=>{
        setCurrentDate(parseInt(e.target.value) || currentDate);
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
     let newAge = Math.round((Math.abs(currentDate - stockingDate))/24 * 60 * 60 *1000)
     setAge(newAge)
    },[currentDate,stockingDate])

    
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Form>
                        <Row className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formStockingDate">
                        <Form.Control type="date"placeholder="Stocking Date" onChange= 
                        {changeHandler} value={stockingDate}/>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formAge">
                        <Form.Control type = "number"placeholder = "Age"
                        value = {age}  onChange={changeCurrentHandler}/>
                        </Form.Group>                        
                    </Row>
                    </Form>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Calculation;
```

Comment: Calculating days between two dates is done the same way whether it is in react or not. The calculation should be very easy to research. Show us what you have tried and where you are getting stuck

Comment: Here, I am using react because I want to get results in the react-bootstrap form. The given code in the above was tried by me. @charlietfl

Comment: I see nothing that tries to calculate the difference between two dates. That's fine you are using react. My point is it is the same calculation regardless of what you are using and is no different because you are using react

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.